# Sum two number using oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, select

When I want to get a sum of two numbers in mysql I can just use

```
select 10 + 15;
```

However, when I try the same in oracle sql i get the following error.

```
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
```

What would be the correct way to sum two numbers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[oracle](/questions/tagged/oracle) doesn't allow queries without a `from` clause. You could use the `dual` dummy table for such purposes:

```
SELECT 10 + 15 FROM dual;
```

Comment: `dual` Oracle documentation:  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/queries009.htm